# error: 'log1p' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin, armadillo, gcc5

I create a simple main function and above it, I include [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) library.

```
#include <armadillo>
```

I compiled it using g++ (version of GCC is 5.3) and under cygwin 64bit on windowse 8. I turned on c++11 option and added `-larmadillo` for linking to armadillo library.

Once I compile the code, I receive such horrible error. The same code runs absolutely fine on windowse XP 32 bit.

```
usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:73:88: note: #pragma message: WAR

NING: #define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11 before #include <armadillo>

     #pragma message ("WARNING: #define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11 before #include <arm

adillo>")



        ^

In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:310:0,

                 from main.cpp:1:

/usr/include/armadillo_bits/arma_cmath.hpp: In function 'float arma::arma_log1p(

float)':

/usr/include/armadillo_bits/arma_cmath.hpp:270:12: error: 'log1p' is not a membe

r of 'std'

     return std::log1p(x);

            ^

compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Makefile:110: recipe for target 'main.o' failed

make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the #if which is generating the warning?  Certainly at gcc 4.9 --std=c++11 generates a value for `__cplusplus` which is not the C++11 defined value (and hence this warning).

Comment: std::log1p should be defined in <cmath>. Verify that the translation units in question have a #include <cmath>

Comment: It is likely that the compiler does not define `log1p(float a)`, which appears in c++11  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log1p/ . Could you try not to use the C++11 feature by adding `#define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11` before `#include <armadillo>`. I know that the developpers of Armadillo are not far away from this forum... They may come up with a better solution !